# PropertyName in Cloud Firestore does not work with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

The annotation `@PropertyName` is not serialized in Kotlin!

> Version: com.google.firebase: firebase-firestore: 17.1.0

Using `@PropertyName` in a Kotlin Android project, it does not serialize the value, only when I use annotation `@JVMField` or create the same class in Java.

```
@JvmField
@PropertyName("championship-name")
val championshipName: String = "",
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Please edit the question to show the entire class that contains the field that's not working (including the imports), the code that writes to the database, and the exact results of the write that don't match your expectations.  We should be able to duplicate your situation on our own.  If you think there's a bug in the Firestore SDK, then file a bug report instead. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Answer (score 7):

Try like this

```
@get:PropertyName("championship-name") @set:PropertyName("championship-name") var championshipName: String = "",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without making the property mutable, just annotate the getter with `@PropertyName`:

```
@get:PropertyName("championship-name") 
val championshipName: String = "",
```